# missing packages on dotcloud

Tags: github, dotcloud

I actually want to load this ruby git repo on Dotcloud 
github com/danielweinmann/catarse

with following guidelines for packages and dependencies

https://github.com/danielweinmann/catarse/wiki/Installing-Catarse-on-Ubuntu-11.10-VMWare

I am getting this output so far with dotcloud.yml included below

https://gist.github.com/3179421

drupin @ freenode

Answer (score 1):

The whole `systempackages:` section should be indented; e.g.::

```
www:
  type: python
  systempackages:
    - foo
    - bar
    - libquux
```

Comment: thanks and i changed some more error but input by andy let me see

Comment: please check my feedback here if you missed   https://dotcloud.zendesk.com/requests/18730